# Most Efficient Way To Keep Commas In Numeric Values In Text Boxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, formatting

Let's say I have a text box, and I have to put a number in that text box.  I want it so that the number always has commas every 3 digits even when the user is adjusting the value.

On the `OnChangeValue` event, I read the value, convert it to double, then write it out again with commas every 3 digits, but then, because I'm rewriting the string, my cursor is back to the beginning of the string.

So now I'm thinking that I can read how many digits into the number the cursor is at before the change, and restore the location afterwards.  But this seems like a lot of clutter for such a simple thing to do.  Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Webforms? MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the framework's `MaskedTextBox` control.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.aspx